# How can I show change over time in a word or bubble cloud?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, animation, d3.js, data-visualization

Let's say someone wanted to show the popularity of the last letter in newborn boys' names over the last 100 years. "n" has risen from ~8% to ~35%, and the rest have, with some fluctuations, mostly decreased to make room for this enormous takeover (all those Justins, Aidens, Jasons, Brians, etc.)

I could always show one histogram for every year and have a slider; in fact, I've done that at http://prooffreader.kissr.com/chart/expt.html (the link is Dropbox-hosted, so it takes a little while to load, sorry; and the x-axis is wrongly aligned, I know what I did wrong thanks to Stackoverflow but haven't gotten around to fixing it.)
I thought it would be less... sterile? ... to have a word cloud (of single letters) or a bubble cloud (maybe they could be the same thing if I made the text in the bubble really big and the bubble transparent). The only problem is showing change over time (either interactively or just an animated gif).

In order to do this, I think the positioning of each word/bubble must be a non-random function of both its present size (easy) and its previous position. There are several word cloud and bubble cloud implementations I've seen, particularly in D3. It's easy enough to change their .js files to change Math.random() into constants to take care of the first criterion, but the second one is escaping me.

When I change values over time, the words/bubbles sometimes "jump" to totally new positions on the other side of the cloud, especially if they decrease in size dramatically. The algorithms are just trying to find the best fit for the data in that set, not taking into account the previous position.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've started looking into force-directed graphs, but that seems like an extremely non-trivial hack. I'm rather new to all of this visualization and javascript stuff, so I'm hoping there might be something obvious I'm missing.

I suppose if an algorithm is not based on the most efficient fit, it may "spread out" over time; perhaps it could be loosened up in the beginning so it's not that obvious.

Comment: You could compute the word cloud layout with the biggest values for each word. Then you just need to adjust the font sizes without having to worry about the position, as the words shouldn't overlap for any values.

Comment: True, that would work -- it might not be as dramatic as my mental image of everything shifting in response to the new sizes of the words/letters/bubbles, but it would certainly be easier to implement. Thank you for helping me think outside my mental box.

Comment: Your other option is to take a more structured approach than a word cloud.  A word cloud really only represents one dimension (size of the word), position is determined purely by aesthetics.  You could create a layout in which position is ordered (e.g. alphabetical list), and then it would be easier to track changes in size of each entry.  You could even make it a matrix (e.g., letters as rows, years as columns) so that you could see all the values at once without a slider.  [This graphic uses a similar layout](http://neuralengr.com/asifr/journals/), but with circles instead of letters/words.